# Is it possible in MOSS to have every newly created site collection only search within the site collection?

Tags: 2007, search, site-collection

Is there a configuration setting or anything that could be done so that when a newly created site collection can only search within itself and nothing outside of that scope? All those site collections are going to be under the same web application and Shared Services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about if you dont create a search center within the sight collection and only use the WSS search rather than SharePoint search.

That way the only scopes you get will be 'This Site' and 'This List'.

Alternatively if you want to use the search center then you will have to create a scope that is Site Collection specific and remove the 'All Sites' scope since that will give you the entire SSP index.